# Storing facebook info to authenticate user?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So I created a facebook app, I then have a user give permission for my app which includes posting to their stream and offline use. Now to post in the future on their stream do I just store their access token and then use the access token in my code to post to their feed? Or do I need to store additional information?

**EDIT**

Im using the Facebook SDK For PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user id and access token associated with it in your database. If you have publish stream permission you generally don't need offline_access. Also Facebook doesn't recommend posting on behalf of a user when the user is offline but using user-initiated posting instead.

hope this helps